Why is this set of functions compact in L^1 (in proof of localization principle by Katznelson)
These are the hypotheses of the localization principle, a theorem in Katznelson's Introduction to Harmonic Analysis (to be found in chapt.2, section 2): Let $f$ be a complex-valued periodic function on $\mathbb R$ with period $2 \pi$, integrable on an interval of length $2 \pi$, $I$ an open interval of $\mathbb R$ such that $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in I$. Before this theorem, he gives a lemma (which I don't reproduce here because my question doesn't address it) which leads easily to the first conclusion of the theorem, namely that the Fourier series of $f$ converges pointwise to $0$ in $I$. The second conclusion is about uniform convergence and I have a question about the first step of the proof of this, which uses afterwards not only the lemma but also part of its proof.
Suppose $I_0$ is a compact subset of $I$ [the author talks about a closed subset, leaving open whether it is meant to be closed in $I$ or in the whole real line - moreover his proof takes $I_0$ to be a sub-interval - but as the case where the length of $I$ exceeds that of a period is totally uninteresting, I guess he imagines a bounded $I$ so that $I_0$ is also bounded and therefore compact if closed in $\mathbb R$ ... and I see no reason for restricting $I_0$ to be an interval]. Now Katznelson says that the following subset of $L^1$ is compact: it consists of the functions $t \mapsto f(t-t_0) / \tan(t/2)$ for $t_0 \in I_0$. In fact he doesn't mention the similar easier fact concerning what one obtains using instead simply $t \mapsto f(t-t_0)$ for the same $t_0$s. Both are needed in the remaining part of the proof, where a formula from the proof of his lemma has to be used. But this isn't a problem for me, nor is probably imho that instead of $t-t_0$ one should use $t+t_0$ because of what has to be done with the formula in the lemma. (This has to do with what happens to the partial sums of a Fourier series when shifting the argument of the functions involved.) Indeed:
To treat the easier case, one can apply the result "the image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact" using as map (depending on $f$) the one that takes a real number $t_0$ to the shifted function $t \mapsto f(t-t_0)$ (that this map is continuous isn't trivial, but easy when f is continuous, and can then be generalized in a way K. shows in chapt. 1 - of course $L^1$ has to be considered as equipped with its standard norm) ... to get the plus sign instead of minus in $t-t_0$, one has only to apply first the change of sign in $\mathbb R$ which is continuous too.
I thought first that the case with the division by a value of tan can be treated in the same manner, given that $t \mapsto f(t+t_0) / \tan(t/2)$ is also in $L^1$ for $t_0 \in I$ (because $f(t+t_0)$ is then zero in a neighborhood of $0$ while the cotangent is bounded outside), but this doesn't work since a shift will not just change $t_0$ but also affect the place where the tangent is taken. Is it possible to prove that the function indicated in this paragraph depends continuously on $t_0$? How?
Edit:
That Katznelson gives a proof of the second conclusion of his theorem only for sub-intervals is after all not a problem, because a compact subset $K$ of an interval $I$ in $\mathbb R$ is always contained in a compact sub-interval of $I$: indeed, the identity map $i$ of $K$ is a real-valued continuous function defined on the compact subspace $K$, thus bounded and - except in the trivial case where $K=\emptyset$ - reaching its bounds $m$ and $M$ (meaning that these are values of $i$); therefore these belong to $K$ and thus also to $I$; and because $K = i(K) \subset [m,M]$ which is then also contained in $I$ (and compact), what I just pretended follows.

It took me long efforts, but finally I have found an answer. I tried on different lines, finally the key moment was when I found an useful linear subspace in $L^1$ (may-be not closed, so not complete, not a Banach, but that doesn't matter here) - it doesn't have a name / symbol as far as I know. It depends on a number $\epsilon > 0$; I might call it $W_\epsilon$. But we will need only one value of $\epsilon$ which will arise in the first part of my proof (depending on $I$ and $I_0$). So I will drop the index $\epsilon$ in my definition of the subspace. The space $L^1$ I am talking about here is that on the (one-dimensional) "torus" $\mathbb R / 2 \pi \mathbb Z$ (equipped with its Haar measure) which can be identified with the space of complex-valued periodic functions on $\mathbb R$ with period $2 \pi$, integrable on an interval of length $2 \pi$.
As suggested we use again that "the image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact". But first I explain how to choose $\epsilon$ and then define $W$.
There is a number $\epsilon > 0$ such that the conditions $t \in \mathbb R, |t| \le \epsilon, t_0 \in I_0$ imply $t+t_0 \in I$. (Remember that $I_0$ is a compact set contained in the open interval $I$.) The proof of this is easy, especially if we use the fact that $I_0$ is contained in a compact sub-interval of $I$ (proof shown in the last part of my question). Of course $\epsilon$ can be taken $< \pi$. In what follows we use this $\epsilon$.
Let $W$ be the set of all $L^1$-functions $g$ (on the torus) such that g as function on $\mathbb R$ satisfies $g^{-1}(0) \supset [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. (The left side of this inclusion is to be understood as the reciprocal image of $0$ by $g$.) One sees easily that $W$ is indeed a linear subspace of $L^1$.
Now I define a linear map $\theta$ from $W$ to $L^1$. Let $g \in W$; put $\theta(g)=h$ where $h(t) = g(t) / \tan(t/2)$ for $t \notin 2 \pi \mathbb Z$ and $h(t)=0$ otherwise. We have $g(t)=0$ and therefore $h(t)=0$ for $-\epsilon \le t \le \epsilon$ (by definition of $W$). When $\epsilon \le t \le 2\pi - \epsilon$, $|1/\tan(t/2)|$ is bounded by $M=1/\tan(\epsilon/2)$. Therefore $\theta(g) \in L^1$ and $||\theta(g)||_1 \le M ||g||_1$. This shows that $\theta$ - which is obviously linear - is also continuous.
On the other hand, we may use that the map $\tau \mapsto f_{-\tau}$, where one defines for $\tau \in \mathbb R$: $f_{-\tau}(t) = f(t+\tau)$ (here $f_{-\tau}$ is a function defined in $\mathbb R$ and it is also in $L^1$ by the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure), is continuous as a map $\mathbb R \to L^1$. (Usually one defines $f_\tau(t) = f(t-\tau)$, that is why I add the minus sign to the index. But this is not so important because the change of sign is itself continuous.) Katznelson proves this in his chapt.1, section 2.1 and I read a may-be slightly different proof in the French book Analyse. Théorie de l'intégration. Convolution et transformée de Fourier (by Marc Briane & Gilles Pagès) in their chapter about convolution in which it is a preliminary. Both proofs of this not so trivial result treat first the case where $f$ is continuous, from which the case $f \in L^1$ is deduced based on the fact that the continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ when the base space is compact (like the torus or $[0,2\pi]$). So proofs for this should not be difficult to find.
Now the (continuous) restriction $\alpha$ of this map to $I_0$ has its values in $W$ since the conditions $t \in \mathbb R, |t| \le \epsilon, \tau \in I_0$ imply $t+\tau\in I$. Indeed because of the hypothesis $f(t)=0$ for $t \in I$, we have when $\tau \in I_0$: for $t \in [-\epsilon.\epsilon]$, $f_{-\tau}(t) = f(t+\tau) = 0$.
The composition $\theta \circ \alpha$ sends $t_0$ to the function $t \mapsto f(t+t_0) / \tan(t/2)$. This completes the proof (the replacement of the plus sign by a minus sign again doesn't matter for the reason already mentioned)

About the family of $W_\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$ I had expressed some doubt (irrelevant for the proof) - I deleted that part of my answer. These subspaces don't cover all of $L^1$, not because their union would only contain functions with value zero in 0. After all, $L^1$ proper isn't made of integrable functions but of equivalence classes of such functions, two of them being equivalent when they agree a.e. (i.e. almost everywhere) ... nevertheless a constant function $\not = 0$ isn't zero a.e. in any neighborhood of 0.
